# Finding Kn from ID vs VDS graph

Tags: mosfet

I have the following simple circuit to obtain characteristics of an N type MOSFET.

[image]

The gate voltage will be swept from **3 to 6 Volts** while the drain voltage will be swept from **0 to 0.5 Volts** to obtain **I<sub>D</sub>** VS **V<sub>DS</sub>** graph for different **V<sub>GS</sub>** values. The threshold voltage is calculated from the SAT condition with a different setup and the MOS will always be in **triode region** with these voltage sweep values.

I am asked to find *"the most precise"* Kn which is equal to **I<sub>D</sub>/(V<sub>DS</sub> *( V<sub>GS</sub>-V<sub>T</sub>))**(Dropping **V<sub>DS</sub><sup>2</sup>** for convenience). But what is meant by *"the most precise"* value?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you measure \$Vt\$, you are approximating \$Kn\$. 
\$Vt\$ will vary device to device. 
To find a precise value for \$Kn\$, additional measurements must be taken.

Comment: VT is already calculated for that particular device as I stated.

Comment: VT is Threshold Voltage not Thermal Voltage

Comment: sorry about that mistake, I fixed it. But I wonder what is meant by "the most precise one"? Does a change in gate voltage affect the "precision" of Kn calculation?

Comment: VT will vary due to doping concentration, and Kn will vary due to gate capacitance. I think the question is asking for a measurement of Kn with the least assumptions.

Comment: It is probably related to gate capacitance which I totally overlooked so far. Thanks a lot for the answers.